# grep finds the pattern "\n}" where it should not?

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find occurences of \n} (a newline before a closing curly bracket) in a text using regex.

However, when I execute `grep "\n}" myfile` with myfile containing only the caracter '}' (no newline), then grep (version 3.7) finds the pattern and displays :

`1:}`

It obviously should not.

In the regex pattern, I tried escaping the '}', I tried calling grep with the -E or -G options to change the regex dialect but grep always finds the pattern in the file, except it is not there.

Why is that ? How can I make grep find this pattern properly ?
I thought it could be an ecoding issue but the file is plain ASCII...
Thank you in advance !

Comment: It seems like `sed` is having trouble too but I couldn't replicate it properly

Comment: `grep` processes one line at a time and strips out the newlines before matching.

Comment: Use `^` to match the beginning of a line, so `^}` matches `}` at the beginning of e line.

Comment: I can't explain why the OP is getting `1:}` in their output, I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Is `1:` part of the file, or are you using `grep -n` to get line numbers?

Comment: `1:` is not part of the file and I don't use the `-n` option.

Answer (score 0):

The shell interpretor was the cause : I was using xonsh when I saw this. I switched to bash and `grep` performed as expected

Comment: The shell shouldn't have any impact on how `grep` behaves. Unless it supercedes the command with its own built-in.

Comment: The [documentation](https://xon.sh/aliases.html?highlight=grep#grep) says that `grep` is aliased to `grep --color==auto`. I don't see how that could cause this problem.

Comment: That means `xonsh` was somehow converting `grep "\n}"` to `grep -n "}"` before executing it. Seems... less than ideal!